# Braintree Paypal getting response "Merchant not found and status fail"

Tags: flutter, paypal, response, paypal-sandbox, braintree-sandbox

Have setup the brain-tree client and server Sdk, php as server side and client side is flutter.

The error i am getting is this:

```
Response of the payment {message: Merchant account not found, status: fail}
```

full response error

```
W/CameraBase(10618): An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
D/OpenGLRenderer(10618): endAllActiveAnimators on 0x97e6eb80 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x9987d180
I/flutter (10618): Response of the payment {message: Merchant account not found, status: fail}
I/flutter (10618): null
E/flutter (10618): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
E/flutter (10618): Receiver: null
E/flutter (10618): Tried calling: length
E/flutter (10618): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
```

My debit and credit card transactions are working properly as i can see transactions using braintree account.

The method for drop_in paypal and credit payments

```
 payNow() async {
    BraintreePayment braintreePayment = new BraintreePayment();
    var data = await braintreePayment.showDropIn(
        nonce: clientNonce, amount: amount, enableGooglePay: true, nameRequired:true);
    print("Response of the payment $data");

   print( data['paymentNonce']);

   paymentNonce =  data['paymentNonce'];

    _SendNoncePostRequest();
  }
```

But when doing with paypal it gives the above response error.

Also to note my country is not supported by paypal and i cant access paypal sandbox.

I am just using braintree sandbox account with provided merchant_id,private and public key.

So does brain tree sandbox account will be enough for testing paypal sand box transactions.Without having the need for paypal sandbox account or it is necessary to link your paypal sandbox account with  braintree to see successful paypal transactions.

If it is necessary what options do i have to perform this without paypal.

But if there is another direction to this response that i don't understood please tell.

Comment: any one who had faced problem like this

Comment: I believe you need to link a PayPal account (either sandbox or production).  Go to Processing->Payment Methods and enable PayPal. After that go to **Options** under the  PP switch. From there you need to enter the PayPal Sandbox Credentials